# How to update data in Fragment UI?

Tags: android

I have the following class extended Fragment:

```
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    private GridView events;

    public DummySectionFragment() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        switch (args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) {
            case 1 : return initializeCalendarScreen(inflater);
            case 2 : return inflater.inflate(R.layout.todo_lists_layout, null);
        }         
        return null;           
    }

    public void updateGridView() {

        int daysInCurrentMonth=(MainActivity.month==1) ? daysInFebruary : COUNT_OF_DAYS_IN_MONTH[MainActivity.month];
        int daysInPrevMonth=(MainActivity.month-1==1) ? daysInFebruary : COUNT_OF_DAYS_IN_MONTH[MainActivity.month-1];
        int daysInNextMonth=(MainActivity.month+1==1) ? daysInFebruary : COUNT_OF_DAYS_IN_MONTH[MainActivity.month+1];

        Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(MainActivity.year, MainActivity.month, 1);
        int startDayOfWeek=calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        List<Integer> dates=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i=0; i<startDayOfWeek-1; i++) {
            dates.add(daysInPrevMonth-i);
        }
        for (int i=0; i<daysInCurrentMonth; i++) {
            dates.add(i+1);
        }

        ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(getActivity(), R.layout.grid_view_cell_layout, R.id.textViewGridCell, dates);
        events.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private View initializeCalendarScreen(LayoutInflater inflater) {
        View layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_layout, null);
        events=(GridView)layout.findViewById(R.id.gridViewCalendar);
        updateGridView();
        return layout;
    }
}
```

It works good (I use it for FragmentPagerAdapter). And I use method updateGridView() from Activity for updating value in GridView. But if I do it I will got NullPointerException, because getActivity() for ArrayAdapter returns null. Please, tell me, how can I update Fragment UI from Activity? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

ONE POSSIBLE SOLUTION IS:

1. Create static global variable context
2. create context = inflater.getContext().
3. Use context to create ArrayAdapter when updating UI.

Change:

```
...=new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(context,...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `Observer` in the Fragment instead of calling `updateGridView()` outside your `Fragment`. Have an `Observer` in your `Fragment` observe an `Observable` in your main `Activity`. When the data needs to be updated, just call the `notifyObservers()` method of the `Observable`. The `Observer` class should be a child class of your Fragment and should look something like this:

```
class UpdateGridObserver implements Observer {
    @Override
    public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {
        // Do stuff like:
        // runOnUiThread is REQUIRED because updating the adapter
        // and ListView from a background thread is not allowed
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            updateGridView();
        });
    }
}
```

This allows for the data to be updated without having to worry about scope and all that jazz. As long as the `Observable` object is accessible to the `Observer` object you should be good to go.

You can extend the `Observable` class (as with any class) as well to have a custom `Observable` object if you need more capability than just notification. It's outside the scope of what I think you are looking for, but I've linked some wikis and howtos below.

Observer-Observable Pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

More: http://www.javaworld.com/jw-10-1996/jw-10-howto.html